# laravel 5.8 scheduler not working automatically have to trigger manual

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am running command `php artisan schedule:run` and it will work . but i want to update thing everyMinute(); automatically without trigger command every time .if i have to trigger it mannualy then what is the meaning of scheduler

1. my command file

```
  public function handle()
    {
        $update = Roi::find(12);
        $update->level = 48;
        $update->save();
    }
```

2.`kernal.php`

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('level:update')->everyTwoMinutes();
    }
```

i am checking updates in `updated_at` timestamp in database

Comment: check at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling its available

Comment: Did you start the scheduler?

Comment: For Laravel 5.8 the correct documentation url would be https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

That might solve your issue, it's the way you start the scheduler:

```
php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

That way you will run every minute and check whatever is due to execute it.

Comment: Guess https://gist.github.com/Splode/94bfa9071625e38f7fd76ae210520d94 is the way for you then. Laravel docs are targeted to a Linux OS

Comment: so it will run on linux hosting ?

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/Splode/94bfa9071625e38f7fd76ae210520d94 windows not supported for command line task schedule

Answer (score 0):

I think `running schedule` not working on windows `locally`
the only way worked for me is to create task in windows and related with .bat file

**note: bat file content is**

```
@ECHO OFF 
php path-of-laravel-project\artisan schedule:run
PAUSE
```